# Using GIT with PHP framework, and updating that framework

Tags: php, git, workflow, fuelphp

I've done some reading on this but figured a specific post might be helpful.

Let's say I'm using FuelPHP framework on some custom projects, and those guys release a new update to the framework.  My project already has a GIT repository of the project with all my custom scripts/views/libraries, etc.

Can I add the updated framework as a remote, and pull from it?  Will it update the framework files without screwing up all of the custom work I did building the app?  I'm trying to take my use of GIT to the next level, making it easy to update frameworks and deploy to my servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd take a look at using [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).  That way, you can use Fuel almost as it's own repository, that can be updated and pulled independent from the rest of your structure.